# uploadify - How can I integrate uploadify.php code into my existing programming?

Tags: php, mysql, uploadify

I have PHP module working very well where I can upload video title & upload actual video file. Currently I can upload larger sizes video too on my website but without displaying any progress status. So I decided to use uploadify but I am bit confused on how to integrate code of uploadify.php file into my existing programming. Because in my existing programming, I auto generate video file name and save video file on server as well as store video details into MySQL database table. Then I tried to put uploadify.php code into video_add_p.php file but it is giving error.

When I write [uploader : 'uploadify.php'], it works fine and upload file on server but doesn't store details in database.

When I write [uploader : 'video_add_p.php'], it gives error "HTTP Error (302)".

Please help on this issue, 
thank you, KRA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in uplodify you can attach a from data like this, so you can grap a post or get data and save into your database

**HTML**

```
<form name="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="video_upload" name="video" placeholder="Select your file to upload">
  <input type="text" id="video_caption" name="caption" placeholder="video caption" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**
you can send whatever through "formData" variable

```
$('#video_upload').uploadify({
    'swf'       : '/includes/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader'  : '/includes/uploadify.php',
    'buttonText': 'browae file(s)...',
    'onUploadStart': function() {
       $("#video_upload").uploadify('settings', 'formData', {'caption':  $('#video_caption').val()});
    }
  });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
   $caption = $_POST['caption'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But sorry for not mentioning earlier that user will enter video title by input text box. So how can I do in that case?

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and get back to you with status.

Comment: Hello, how can I check on uploadify.php file that video title is passed properly? because nothing happens when I try to print that value on uploadify.php.

Comment: Hello, print_r($_POST) is not working but good thing is that using formData, I can now pass values to uploadify.php and also able to store into database. Only one issue is that after successful upload on server and storing data into database, I am getting error in upload queue like this - "test001.mpg (901KB) - HTTP Error (302)". Please help if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624726/http-error-302-using-uploadify take a look on this one

Comment: Thanks, it works for me... problem is solved. Now when I cancel the upload in between, file upload is cancelled but query is triggered so data are added into database. Can you tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadsuccess/ you can use ajax to save record with success upload

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to make file name unique

```
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .TARGET FOLDER NAME . '/';
$ext = substr($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], strrpos($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], '.') + 1);
$targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . uniqid().'.'.$ext;
```